# Get a variable from another file in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables

I'm kind of new to wordpress coding and I've been trying to get a variable from another file.

I have this variable $final_cat_url in /custom/last-category.php that I want to reuse in customtemplate.php.

I've read lots of explanations and the codex, but it's still not working.

I've tried to use the following code in customtemplate.php

```
get_template_part( 'custom/last-category', null, array('my_final_cat_url'=> $final_cat_url));  
echo $args['my_final_cat_url'];
```

Can you help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you use `get_template_part()` you are passing the arguments into the template part. When you pass the variables in you can then use the variable like `echo $args['key'];` in the template part itself. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do but it might be better to generate the variable elsewhere and pass it into the template, rather than generating it in the template and trying to retrieve it from there.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I created last-category.php just to generate this variable #final_cat_url because i would like to reuse it in three customtemplate1.php files (2, 3,4),  For exemplo: I have a slider code (with some php and html code) that I reuse with get_template_part() and it's ok, but variables seem so complicated.

echo $args['key'];  can this 'key' parameter be a variable like $key, that will return a value?  .. I just don't understand what 'key' means in this context.  Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: I will suggest pass the variable as a reference instead as an arguments, if I understand you send the $final_cat_url to the custom/last-category.php via get_template_part(), the thing is that when you send that variable to the template, in really you are sending a copy, if you want to reuse the value processed in last-category.php you must send as a reference: get_template_part( 'custom/last-category', null, array('my_final_cat_url'=> &$final_cat_url));  and now you can reuse the value of $final_cat_url in customtemplate.php with the new value proccesed in last-category.php

Comment: Can you not do the work to get `$final_cat_url` in customtemplate.php? Then you could use `get_template_part()` three times, once for each of the three template parts from there. Or, if you're making a theme, you could make a function in functions.php and use it from there. https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

Comment: @Cristino , thank you so much for your reply and your time. I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: @sdexp, I will try to do that. Sorry for my delay. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your functions.php file:

```
function includeWithVariables($filePath, $variables = array(), $print = true){
    $output = NULL;
    if(file_exists($filePath)){
        // Extract the variables to a local namespace
        extract($variables);

        // Start output buffering
        ob_start();

        // Include the template file
        include $filePath;

        // End buffering and return its contents
        $output = ob_get_clean();
    }
    if ($print) {
        print $output;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Instead of using get_template_part(), use this:

```
<?php includeWithVariables('file_to_include.php', array('final_cat_url' => $final_cat_url)); ?>
```

In the file you included:

```
<?php echo $final_cat_url; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry for my delay. I will try to use this code and then I will reply it again, ok? Thanks a lot!